# Code adapted to RX Completable not blocking onSubscribe thread

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, scheduler, rx-android

I have some legacy, non-RX code that does some networking work by spawning a new Thread.
When the work finishes, it invokes one method on a callback.

I don't have control over the thread this code runs on. It's legacy, and it spawns a new `Thread` by itself.

This can be simplified in something like:

```
interface Callback {
    void onSuccess();
}

static void executeRequest(String name, Callback callback) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(" Starting... " + name);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(" Finishing... " + name);
            callback.onSuccess();
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
    }).start();
}
```

I want to convert this to an RX `Completable`. To do so I use `Completable#create()`.
The implementation of the `CompletableEmitter` calls the `executeRequest` passing of implementation of the `Callback` that signals when the request has finished.

I also print a log trace when subscribed to help me debugging.

```
static Completable createRequestCompletable(String name) {
        return Completable.create(e -> executeRequest(name, e::onComplete))
                .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println("Subscribed to " + name));
}
```

This works as expected. The `Completable` completes only after the "request" finishes and the callback is invoked.

Problem is that when subscribing to this these completables in a `trampoline` scheduler, it does not wait for the first request to finish before subscribing to the second request.

This code:

```
final Completable c1 = createRequestCompletable("1");
c1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()).subscribe();

final Completable c2 = createRequestCompletable("2");
c2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()).subscribe();
```

Outputs:

```
Subscribed to 1
    Starting... 1 
Subscribed to 2
    Starting... 2 
    Finishing... 1 
    Finishing... 2
```

As you see, it subscribes to the second `Completable` before the first `Completable` has completed, even if I'm subscribing in `trampoline`.

I'd like to queue the `completables`, so that the second waits for the first to finish, outputting this:

```
Subscribed to 1
    Starting... 1 
    Finishing... 1
Subscribed to 2
    Starting... 2  
    Finishing... 2
```

I'm sure the problem is related to the work being done in a worker thread. If the implementation of the `Completable` does not spawn a new thread it works as expected.
But this is legacy code and what I'm trying to do is adapting it to RX  without modifying.

NOTE: the requests are executed in different points of the program - I cannot use `andThen` or `concat` to implement the serialised execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to execute the `Completables` sequentially by explicitly blocking the subscription `Thread` with a `Latch`.
But I don't think this is the idiomatic way to do it in RX, and I still don't understand why I need to do this and the Thread is not blocked until the `Completable` completes.

```
static Completable createRequestCompletable(String name) {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    return Completable.create(e -> {
        executeRequest(name, () -> {
            e.onComplete();
            latch.countDown();
        });
        latch.await();
    })
    .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> System.out.println("Subscribed to " + name));
}
```